# How to target specific links in email clients (Microsoft Outlook)?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to add a word break to some email links, but don't want to apply the style to all the content.

If I apply the following CSS, all content (including the links) breaks onto the following line:

```
html, body, table {
    word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

This results in: https://gyazo.com/60e081771f7de04402da60dcad63ea6e

However, the line break doesn't work when I try to apply it only to specific elements using the following css:

```
table tr td span.word-break * {
    word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

This css results in: https://gyazo.com/23f0a413e21b668bc713dbb7a5af90ff

The HTML i'm using is:

```
<span class='word-break'><a href='www.google.com'>long_link_000000000000000000000</a></span>
<span class='word-break'>test.email@evenlongertest.com</span>
```

I have tried multiple variations of the CSS but can't seem to apply the style specifically to the links. If I change the colour to red to test the selection, it works in the browser but not in the email client.

Comment: Try with an inline style="..." attribute? - web/email clients have limited/quirky support for CSS & HTML.

Comment: @AlexK. Tried to add it with inline styling and unfortunately didn't work, that's why i'm really confused.

Comment: The style in your question seems to work for me in outlook. Not sure what's going on in your html.

Comment: @10101010 You were able to apply the word break only to the links and not the normal text?

Comment: Try to add these to the table cells housing the contents. So either add the style inline on those two cells, or add a class to both of those cells and set it in the head. Inline is your best bet as not all email clients read CSS from the head by default.

Comment: It would be great if you could post the entire section of code that has these sections in. Always best to do that to give us a better idea of what we're working with.

Comment: @Xander Yup. Works for for both as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

For some reason the rule (word-break) only took effect when applied to the parent `<td>` element.

It worked when I used the following (ugly):

HTML:

```
<table class='word-break'><tr><td><a href='mailto:test.email@evenlongertest.com'>test.email@evenlongertest.com</a></td></tr></table>
```

CSS:

```
table.word-break tr td {
    word-break: break-all;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. The parent should element should be where declarations like this are made, not the elements themselves. In general (for email), it's always best to define styles on tables and table cells, only leaving small variations for span tags and a tags when you need to, like when adding/removing text decoration and colour.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein Yes I will likely make the css more efficient, this was just trying to discover what did/didn't work etc :) Thanks for the suggestion